# Error when trying to edit the header of an envi file?

Tags: editing, error, envi

I have a file with the following Metadata in Envi 5.3

[image]

when I click on `Edit Metadata` or when I try to access the option through `Raster Management > Edit ENVI Header`, I get the error:
[image]
Does anyone know what's the cause of the error?
Is it a bug in 5.3 version?
Or normally I can't access header of files that are imported from PolSARpro?
Do you know any other way to edit the header (within ENVI or outside)? especially map_info part?

Comment: You can edit it with a text editor. If you don't know which fields add in header file, use another raster as a master file (ENVI resources has a lot of examples)